# Fixed position menu, contents outside viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, viewport, fixed

I have a nav menu that takes up the full height of the viewport using min-height, it is also fixed position, but this presents an issue.

```
.menu{
   min-height:100vh;
   height:auto;
   position:fixed;
}
```

The contents inside the menu can display further down than the viewport, if viewed in small browser windows or resolutions like mobile, so you can't see the last menu options.

I'm looking for the best approach to this, whether it's dynamically changing the css position with jQuery (which seems to be the solution used for the WordPress admin menu) or by adjusting the top or margin position on scroll like in this example:

https://queen-theme.myshopify.com/

I want that same user experience, so the element acts (or gives the impression) of having an absolute position until the bottom end of it comes into the view, then it would become fixed position.

These menus are pretty common so I'm sure there's a few ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the @media CSS rule which will apply the CSS properties depending on certain conditions. The example below will display the screen's background color in lightblue for screen size 500px or less.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
body {
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

}

You can find more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)